# Merging staging table to prod slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, etl

I am doing those two transactions, one delete and one insert. However, the delete is really slow. I have already got both column1 and column2 indexed in both prod and staging tables. Is there a faster way to do this? I have tried using join, but the performance is the same. The 'explain' for the delete is attached. The table creation and table status are also attached[image]

DELETE a FROM tablename a where exists (select 1 FROM staging_table b WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2)

INSERT INTO tablename a (column1, column2, column3, column4) SELECT 'column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM staging_table

Joins I did:
DELETE a FROM tablename a join staging_table u
on a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2

DELETE a FROM tablename a join (select distinct column1, column2 from staging_table) b where a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2;

Should I have more indices or less?
enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please POST TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE staging_table; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'tablename'; and D) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE staging_table;  for analysis.

Comment: Could you also post your Query where you tried using JOIN to accomplish the same task?

Comment: I have attached the information. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: I do not see the JOIN version to accomplish this task or an EXPLAIN to go with the JOIN. Maybe we could Skype Talk soon. See profile and we are in GMT -06 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the `DELETE` is doing a big table scan.  But I see a few ways to make it work better.

Do you really need col2 and col3 to be `TEXT`?  In particular, do they need to be bigger than 255 characters?  What version of MySQL are you using?  (The limit may be 191 or something higher than 255.)

Prefixing: `INDEX(col1(16), ...)` is essentially useless.  If you can avoid `TEXT`, you can use the useful `INDEX(col1, col2, col3)`, which should solve your problem.

Also, I see that col1 is either `INT` or `VARCHAR(100)`.  Do you really need the difference?  That, too, may be preventing performance.

If you can't shrink the column definition, I will present a more complex solution.

Another potential issue:  I see that both tables are "large" and only 7:1 ratio of row count.  This may lead to forcing full table scans, too.  What percentage of the main table will be deleted?  (I need to know so I can decide what advice to give next.)